# Adding Navigator Support for a custom programming Language in Netbeans API

Tags: netbeans

I'v added support for a custom programming Language as  described in Netbeans (using ver 7.0) I want to add Navigator Support for that too but i can't find a gud place/ gud example to start with [link]][1](http://bits.netbeans.org/dev/javadoc/org-netbeans-spi-navigator/org/netbeans/spi/navigator/doc-files/BasicNavPanelImpl_java)

But i want it to display in such a way that when we click on navigator nodes, it shud goto the corresponding place in editor..

eg: if in my language, suppose value1  is there and value1 has to be displayed in nav tree under val_imp..Plz tell me hw to do this too..:-(

And once itz shown, whenever i click on the nodes, i wanna go to the corresponding place where value1 is there in editor..

[PS:I'm new to NetBeans APIs but gud with java..]

Thanks in Advance...
Rahul Chandran